# Phony targets not working on windows make

Tags: c++, c, windows, gnu-make

I am trying to make a phony target on make so that my "all" target doesn't run every time even if the prerequisite files haven't changed, but make still runs every target every time I run it.

Here is an example Makefile:

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -Wall

.PHONY: all
all: testing testing2

testing: testing.cpp

testing2: testing2.cpp

clean:
    del *.exe *.o
```

The due to declaring all as a phony target using .PHONY, the intended result is that by running make, the "testing" and "testing2" targets should only be ran if their respective results (testing.exe and testing2.exe) are older than their prerequisites (testing.cpp and testing2.cpp). However, every time make is run, both targets are ran as well. I am using make on windows installed via chocolatey, make --version is GNU Make 4.3 Built for Windows32.

Do phony targets not work on make windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your rules say you'll build the files `testing` and `testing2`.  But your recipes don't build those files, they build the files `testing.exe` and `testing2.exe`.

So when make runs, it looks for the file `testing` to see if it's up to date and it doesn't exist, so make runs the recipe, which builds `testing.exe`.  Then the next time make runs, it looks for the file `testing` to see if it's up to date and it doesn't exist, so make runs the recipe, which builds `testing.exe`.  Etc. etc.

This has nothing to do with PHONY which only applies to `all` so why would it be related to rebuilding `testing`?

You need to name your targets in make with the same name of the file that your recipe creates.

Comment: If I change "testing" and "testing2" to "testing.exe" and "testing2.exe" respectively, make doesn't build anything at all now and always returns with "make: Nothing to be done for 'all'." This also happens if I were to run "make testing.exe". (and yes, the .exe-s are not created)

Comment: Well, it won't build them if they're up to date.  If it says "nothing to be done" then all the targets are indeed up to date.  That's the entire idea behind make: it only runs commands when they are needed, and doesn't run commands when they are not.  It's really not clear from your question what you want to happen.  Maybe you should edit your question, and cut and paste the command you ran and the output you got, and explain why that output was wrong or what you wanted to happen instead.

Comment: Your answer is right, it's just that make doesn't have implicit rules for generating .exe targets, so I also had to add a general rule for compiling .exe targets